# Getting Index in a vector via interators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to get the index of an element pointed by an iterator.

```
struct job{
    int start_time;
    int finish_time;
    int profit;
};


int latest_non_conflicting_job(std::vector<job>& vec, std::vector<job>::size_type& i)
{
    for(std::vector<job>::reverse_iterator it = vec.rbegin()-i; it != vec.rend(); it++){

                if(*it.finish_time <= vec[i].start_time){
                return it-vec.begin();
            }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
    {
        std::vector<job> vec = {{3, 10, 20}, {1, 2, 50}, {6, 19, 100}, {2, 100, 200}};
        latest_non_conflicting_job(vec, vec.size());
        return 0;
    }
```

It shows me the error:

```
error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::vector<job>::reverse_iterator {aka std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<job*, std::vector<job> > >}' and 'std::vector<job>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<job*, std::vector<job> >}')
```

which if I'm correctly understanding is that since my vector contains elements of type "job" I need to overload the -operator for it to work.

One method that I know is that I can traverse the vector by indices to get to my result.

Is there any other way for me to get the index of the element point by iterator without overloading the operator?
It's still quite an unrefined code since I'm not that good yet with iterators and vectors so overlook that please.

Comment: I don't think i fully understand what your code is supposed to do. There are several issues: This `vec.rbegin()-i` decreases a `begin` iterator which is meant to be incremented. This `vec[i]` performs and access to `vec[vec.size()]` (because you pass in `vec.size()` which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to implement any operator. The problem is that you use two different types of iterators, `iterator` and `reverse_iterator`. You can always access the *normal* `iterator` pointing at the next element using `base()`.

```
return it.base() - vec.begin() - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). If you want the index from the end:

```cpp
return std::distance(vec.rbegin(), it);
```

or from the start:

```cpp
return std::distance(it, vec.rend()) - 1;
```